# custom NSCursor is broken

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, nscursor

I have the following code to set cursor from existing CGImage:

```
    NSPoint   hotspot = ...;
    CGImageRef cgimg = ...;

    if(!cgimg)
        return nullptr;
    NSImage* nsimg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg size:NSZeroSize];
    if(!nsimg)
        return nullptr;

    NSCursor* pcur = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage: nsimg hotSpot: hotspot];
    if(!pcur)
        return nullptr;

    [nsimg release];

    // later in the code I set it as current:
    [pcur set];
```

Problem is that it renders inconsistently, sometimes it looks OK, sometimes it shows garbage:
[image: broken cursor]

I am using exactly the same CGImageRef that is rendered OK as normal image (that one below the box).

Any idea what problem could be?

Stock cursors in the same application are rendered OK. That is on OS X "El Capitan" if that matters.

Comment: i don't think you should be calling [nsimg release]. ARC is enabled by default isn't it?

Comment: ARC is off in that project.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

It seem like OS X uses some autorelease pool or the like to store intermediate results.

In my implementation I am creating cursor in one place and use in another - in response of mouse move. It seems that in this case OS X is trying to use memory that was freed.

In order to fix that I was forced to use `[pcur push]; [pcur pop];` sequence to convince OS X to create cursor immediately:

```
NSPoint   hotspot = ...;
CGImageRef cgimg = ...;

if(!cgimg)
    return nullptr;
NSImage* nsimg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg size:NSZeroSize];
if(!nsimg)
    return nullptr;

NSCursor* pcur = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage: nsimg hotSpot: hotspot];
if(!pcur)
    return nullptr;

[nsimg release];

[pcur push]; [pcur pop]; // this is mandatory to force cursor structures to be created.

// store pcur for later use ...
```